# How to triple even numbers in a list?

Tags: list, haskell

```
tripleEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
tripleEven list = case list of
    []     -> []
    [x:xs]
        | (x `mod` 2) == 0 = triple x tripleEven xs
        | otherwise        = tripleEven xs
            where triple = (3*)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
    parse error on input `='
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
71 |         | (x `mod` 2) == 0 = triple x tripleEven xs
```

I want it to go through a list and if number is even then triple it. If it is odd then move to the next number till the end. I am new to Haskell and only learning syntax. Would be glad if someone could explain what exactly is wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: do you want to keep the odd numbers in the output?, i.e. should `tripleEven [1,2,3,4]` be `[6,12]` or `[1,6,3,12]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. you use `[x:xs]` as the non-empty list pattern. A list however has two *data constructors*: `[]` and `(x:xs)` (note the round brackets, in fact the brackets are not really part of the constructor, it is only the colon operator `(:)`);
2. at the right side, you need to construct a new list. With `triple x tripleEven xs`, you do not construct a new list: you first calculate `triple x`, and then Haskell aims to perform a function call with that value as function.
3. you also omit odd values: in case the value is `odd`, you perform recursion on the list, hence you do not put these into the result.

We can fix the issues into:

```
tripleEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
tripleEven [] = []
tripleEven (x:xs) | even x = (3*x) : tripleEven xs
                  | otherwise = x : tripleEven xs
```

But here you basically perform a *mapping*: you can call the function to every element of the list, so we can construct a special mapping function with:

```
tripleEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
tripleEven = map f
    where f x | even x = 3 * x
              | otherwise = x
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive way to write the function where I just fixed the bugs that I noticed in your code.

```
tripleEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
tripleEven [] -> []
tripleEven (x: xs) = case mod x 2 of
  0 -> (3*x) : tripleEven xs
  _ -> tripleEven xs

tripleEven [1,2,3,4]
# outputs
[6, 12]
```

`TripleEven` can also be considered as a `map` & `filter` operation or a list comprehension

```
tripleEven xs = map (*3) $ filter even xs
tripleEven xs = [x*3 | x <- xs, even x]
```

Finally, if you want to define `triple` in a where clause:

```
tripleEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
tripleEven [] = []
tripleEven (x: xs) = case mod x 2 of
  0 -> trip x : tripleEven xs
         where trip = (*3)    
  _ -> tripleEven xs
```

Comment: I don't think that OP wanted the odd numbers to be removed from the output.

Comment: I interpreted "If it is odd then move to the next number till the end" as skip odd numbers, but I see how it can be interpreted differently

Answer (score 0):

List type is a functor and also monad. So i believe the proper way of doing this job is just using `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` over the list. However only for the list type we already have the `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` function which is exactly the same of `fmap`.

So;

```
Prelude> let trev = map (\n -> if even n then n*3 else n)
Prelude> trev [1,2,3,4]
[1,6,3,12]
```

should do the job perfectly and it's aready been mentioned.

We can handle this task from a monadic perspective as well. Then we need a monadic function to run through our list elements. What makes our lambda function monadic here is the `return` instructions.

```
Prelude> let trev ns = ns >>= \n -> if even n then return (n*3) else return n
Prelude> trev [1,2,3,4]
[1,6,3,12]
```